# Matching 3+ Title Case Word in a single pcre expression

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I am looking for a single pcre (ver. 3.85) compatible regular expression that matches a string composed of three or more title case words but does not match any string containing words starting with lower-case letter.
E.g.:

```
"Gaius Julius Caesar" should match
"Gaius Caesar" should not match
"Gaius Julius Caesar Rome" should match
"Gaius julius Caesar" should not match
```

Tried

```
(\b[A-Z]\w+\b){3,}
```

with no success.

Any hint?

Comment: NO. 'julius' is a word starting with lower-case letter

Comment: Preferably, I would like to match lower-case letters, digits, underscore and comma `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
(\b[A-Z]\w+\b\s??){3,}
```

Here is the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO1bI0/2)

```
(\b[A-Z]\w+\b)(\s+\b[A-Z]\w+\b){2,}
```

Here is the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hI6gA2/1)

Comment: I designed the regex to work with strings on one line (no multiline support).

Comment: @fiedi Thnx a lot. The 'tester demo' is great!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below pcregrep command,

```
$ pcregrep -o -M '^[A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+){2,}$' file
Gaius Julius Caesar
Gaius Julius Caesar Rome
```

OR

Try the below command if the following chars after the starting uppercase letter must be in lowercase.

```
$ pcregrep -o -M '^[A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+){2,}$' file
Gaius Julius Caesar
Gaius Julius Caesar Rome
```